# In subprocess.Popen, which file does bufsize apply to?

Tags: python, stream, subprocess, popen, buffering

I'm in need of setting the `stderr` stream in a [`Popen`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) call to line-buffered. I discovered the `bufsize` argument, but it doesn't say which of the 3 (`stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`) files it's actually applied to.

- Which file does the `bufsize` argument
  modify?
- How do I modify the other
  file buffering modes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the source, Luke :-) `/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py`:

```
if p2cwrite is not None:
    self.stdin = os.fdopen(p2cwrite, 'wb', bufsize)
if c2pread is not None:
    if universal_newlines:
        self.stdout = os.fdopen(c2pread, 'rU', bufsize)
    else:
        self.stdout = os.fdopen(c2pread, 'rb', bufsize)
if errread is not None:
    if universal_newlines:
        self.stderr = os.fdopen(errread, 'rU', bufsize)
    else:
        self.stderr = os.fdopen(errread, 'rb', bufsize)
```

So it seems it uses `bufsize` in all of them, no way to be specific.